# (Sketchup C API) Set mm as units of newly created model?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I see that there is a way to get units SUModelGetUnits from the model. But no method to Set the units for the model/file.

So, is it possible to set the units?
If yes, what is the method or is there any other indirect way - such that the new file gets saved with "Millimeters" units?

Note:This question has been posted earlier as part of this thread http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=180%26amp;t=57909.
Since this is a different question from the original thread I have added it separately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to set the units using the SketchUp C API.  You just need to use the UnitsOptions options manager to set the LengthFormat and the LengthUnit.

The UnitsOptions/LengthFormat value for Decimal is 0.
The UnitsOptions/LengthUnit value for millimeters is 2.

Here's some sample code that sets these values:

```
// Get the options manager
SUOptionsManagerRef options_manager = SU_INVALID;
SUModelGetOptionsManager(my_model, &options_manager);

// Get the UnitsOptions options provider
SUOptionsProviderRef options_provider = SU_INVALID;
SUOptionsManagerGetOptionsProviderByName(options_manager, "UnitsOptions", 
                                         &options_provider);

// Make a new typed value with value for mm
SUTypedValueRef typed_value = SU_INVALID;
SUTypedValueCreate(&typed_value);
SUTypedValueSetInt32(typed_value, 2);

// Set the value for LengthFormat to Decimal
SUTypedValueSetInt32(typed_value, 0);
SUOptionsProviderSetValue(options_provider, "LengthFormat", typed_value);

// Set the value for LengthUnit to mm
SUTypedValueSetInt32(typed_value, 2);
SUOptionsProviderSetValue(options_provider, "LengthUnit", typed_value);
```

You can find the full documentation for options provider [here](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/su-api/options__provider_8h.html), which includes the breakdown of the various options providers, options, and values available.

Hope this helps.

Paul